# How do I fix my AMD/ATI GPU drivers (temp is 83 C at idle)?

Tags: ati, gpu, temperature

I am using a Sager laptop with an AMD Radeon HD 6970M 256bit w/2GB GDDR5 and an Intel® Core™ i7-2720QM.  When I boot to Ubuntu 12 the CPU is fine and idles at a good temperature, but the GPU is in the high 70s and goes into the low 80s.

I tried installing all the proprietary drivers and the post release updates failed to install.  Do I need to install Catalyst?

Comment: For the record, GPUs tend to run hotter in laptops, 75 - 85 isnt a horrible temp for a GPU on a laptop, especially with something that powerful.

Comment: I don't know... GPUs certainly do run a lot hotter than any other component, but idling along, I'd be surprised by 30-40C over ambient, and outright frightened of anything above that.

Comment: for reference i am working with windows 7 right now and it is 44c at idle, 80c would be running a 720 p game, 90c is running 1080p starcraft

Answer (score 1):

This issue does not get enough attention from anybody. The open source ATI Driver lets the GPU run much too hot. I advise everybody to use the FGLRX driver. Ideally through  the repositories (via Additional Drivers) so that you don't have to reinstall after every kernel update.